# Workaround AJAX calling without directly calling WordPress backend (Admin dashboard) because it is restricted to the end user (the public)

Tags: themes, ajax, forms

Hi everyone please I would like to put a topic up for discussion because I need help asap
I have a problem at work we developed a WordPress website and delivered it to the client we are in the final stages.

They wanted to hide WordPress backend (admin login and dashboard (wp-admin) ) from the end user (the public)
and they did hide it but later we found out that image upload on a certain form created using a WordPress theme is making ajax calls to the backend
which now creates a problem cause the end user is forbidden from accessing any link that falls under "website.com/wp-admin"

So any suggestions ??

And please guys solutions with minor impact to the whole project because it is in the final stages.

Because the project is in the final stages, we can't make an entire overhaul of the project.
Also I am using HideMyWpGhost plugin for security if that information is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that whitelisting the endpoint is not possible, as this is the simplest solution here.

It will be a little workaround here, but you can try to replace your AJAX endpoint, with a REST API endpoint.

Your main upload logic should stay the same, request will be similar. Maybe you can even use the default WordPress endpoint:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/

If no, just register your own endpoint:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/